# Using observables in react-query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables, react-query

I am building out an app and planning to use rxjs for Observables. However, I like react-query cache functionality and would like to merge them together to get it working.

I am facing an issue where the error code is not clear to me.

Please advice.

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { useQueryStream } from './useQueryStream';
import API from './apiService';
import './style.css';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const Hello: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const fetchPokemon = <T>(): Observable<T[]> => {
    const data =  API.get<T[]>('pokemon?limit=100&offset=0').pipe(
      take(1),
      catchError(err => of(console.log(err)))
    ) as Observable<T[]>;

    console.log(data)
  };

  const result = useQueryStream('data', fetchPokemon);
  return <>{JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}</>;
};

export default Hello;
```

I am also extending react-query to accept an observable and subscribe to it and send the data.

```
import { QueryFunction, useQuery, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import { Observable, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { UseQueryOptions } from 'react-query/types/react/types';

export const useQueryStream = (
  queryKey: string,
  fetcher: QueryFunction,
  config?: UseQueryOptions
) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const queryResult = useQuery(queryKey, fetcher, config);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (queryResult.data instanceof Observable) {
      queryResult.data.subscribe({
        next: data => {
          queryClient.setQueryData(queryKey, (currentQueryData: any) => {
            currentQueryData && combineLatest(currentQueryData, data);
          });
        },
        error: error => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [queryKey, queryResult.data]);

  console.log('queryResult', queryResult);

  return queryResult;
};
```

This is my stackblitz link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3tqgbx?file=Hello.tsx

Please advice on how I fix the error and how I get the data back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a `.tsx` file, you cannot use the generic `<T>` as you have because it will be interpreted as an opening component/element tag:

You can use regular function syntax instead:

```
function fetchPokemon<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
  ...
}
```

However, if you really want to use an arrow function, you can use:

```
const fetchPokemon = <T,>(): Observable<T[]> => {
  ...
}
```

...or:

```
const fetchPokemon = <T extends {}>(): Observable<T[]> => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I used a comma and stackblitz kept removing it as there was no second argument. I see the json now. I dont see the data property in the JSON though. what am I doing wrong in useQueryStream?

Comment: @a2441918 I think you need to `return data` from your `fetchPokemon` function, and also `queryClient.setQueryData(queryKey, data)`

Comment: Thank you. That worked. what about the currentQueryData? Should I be concerned? I got the original source code from here: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/538#issuecomment-864611056

Comment: Will you need to combine with previous data? Won't your API call observable only emit once anyway? If so, maybe you can `return data.toPromise()` from `fetchPokemon` and remove the `useEffect` altogether...

Comment: So I  did is to remove useQueryStream and just use useQuery with returning a promise from the data and it worked.